# initialisation of atomic init

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic

So in my code there is the snippet:

```
std::atomic<uint>* atomic_buffer       = reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<uint>*>(data);
const size_t       num_atomic_elements = svm_data_size / sizeof(std::atomic<uint>);

for (i = 0; i < num_atomic_elements; i++)
{
    std::atomic_init(&atomic_buffer[i], std::atomic<uint>(0));
}
```

However, on execution, the error returned is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'atomic_init'
...
note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_Tp' ('unsigned int' vs. 'int')
atomic_init(volatile atomic<_Tp>* __o, _Tp __d) _NOEXCEPT
```

Any one had a similar issue?

Cheers.

Comment: Does `data` actually hold an array of live `atomic<uint>` objects? Why are you not just using placement-`new`?

Comment: Do you really need `reinterpret_cast`? Can you create the atomics the regular way?

Comment: If the first parameter of `std::atomic_init` is `std::atomic<uint>*`, the second parameter needs to be `uint`.

Comment: What is `data`? Where does `data` point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code it appears that you're trying to create `std::atomic<uint>` objects out of "raw memory". If that's the case then you need to use placement `new` to begin the lifetime of such an object before using it. Also, `&atomic_buffer[i]` can be spelled `atomic_buffer + i`. So your code should be:

```
new (atomic_buffer + i) std::atomic<uint>(0);
```

The `std::atomic_init` function should only be used on default-constructed `std::atomic<T>` objects, and is completely unnecessary as of C++20. (Even if you don't have C++20 yet, you can already stop using `std::atomic_init`. Just remember to always give `std::atomic<T>` objects an explicit value upon construction. This will ensure that your code won't change behaviour in C++20.)